# Bulk Convert File Fields to Assets

Tags: assets

I'm retrofitting Assets into an existing site and need to convert all of the existing file fields to Assets. All the file fields use the same upload directory and options, so I tried a query:

```
UPDATE 
    exp_channel_fields
SET 
    field_type = 'assets',
    field_settings = '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'
WHERE 
    field_type = 'file'
```

That worked OK, but I guess Assets runs some extra functions to convert existing field values, which only seems to work if I manually click "update" from within the field settings in the control panel.

Is there a quick & easy way to bulk-convert those field values so they're compatible with Assets?